# SimpleXML framework: element with element or text

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I must to parse XML which can have two forms:

```
<Command><Variable/></Command>
```

or:

```
<Command>some text</Command>
```

How can I do this? When I try to declare both `@Element` and `@Text` in class responsible for `Command` parsing then exception is thrown when I try to parse XML to instance of this class.

My current version of code:

```
@Root(name = "Command", strict = false)
public class AppCommand {

    @Element(name = "Variable", required = false)
    @Getter
    private Variable variable;

    @Text(required = false)
    @Getter
    private String content;
```

}

And exception is: `Text annotation @org.simpleframework.xml.Text(required=false, empty=, data=false) on field 'content' private java.lang.String com.example.AppCommand.content used with elements in class com.example.AppCommand`

Comment: show the code you achieved till now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution (not beautiful, but works and doesn't require much work to implement):

```
    private static class SerializerWithPreprocessor extends Persister {

        public SerializerWithPreprocessor(RegistryMatcher matcher, Format format) {
            super(matcher, format);
        }

        @Override
        public <T> T read(Class<? extends T> type, String source) throws Exception {
            source = source.replaceFirst("<Command (.*)>([[\\w||[+=]]&&[^<>]]+)</Command>", "<Command $1><Content>$2</Content></Command>");
            return super.read(type, source);
        }
    }
```

So I just created new Serializer class. This class use regular expressions to change `Text` element inside `Command` into normal `Element`. Then I can use:

```
@Root(name = "Command", strict = false)
public class AppCommand {

    @Element(name = "Variable", required = false)
    @Getter
    private Variable variable;

    @Element(name = "Content", required = false)
    @Getter
    private String content;
}
```

and during deserialization everything works like I wanted to.

Comment: Where I shoudl to use `SerializerWithPreprocessor` class?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Simple can't deal with this.

**`Command.java`**:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Text;

@Root
public class Command {

    @Element(required = false, name = "Variable")
    private Variable variable;

    @Text(required = false)
    private String text;    
}
```

**`Variable.java`**:

```
class Variable {
}
```

**`SOPlayground.java`**:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer;
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;

public class SOPlayground {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        String xml1 = "<Command><Variable/></Command>";
        String xml2 = "<Command>some text</Command>";

        serializer.validate(Command.class, xml1);
        serializer.validate(Command.class, xml2);
    }

}
```

This does compile but it does not run:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.simpleframework.xml.core.TextException: Text annotation @org.simpleframework.xml.Text(data=false, required=false, empty=) on field 'text' private java.lang.String de.lhorn.so.Command.text used with elements in class de.lhorn.so.Command
```

It looks like can not have both `@Element` and `@Text` members.

Comment: Yes, you're obviously right. It compile but does not run (I probably wrote "doesn't compile" because I get this exception during test execution). Anyway I will be thankful for any suggestion how to omit this issue

Comment: (my first idea is to always save content of `Command ` to String object and then to try parse this string if it maches `<Variable/>` but it doesn't work well)

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea. Simple seems not to be able to handle mixed element/text content. Can you change the XML?

Comment: I don't think so, I'm responsible only for client part of application and I'm afraid it will be very complicated to change API on the server part.

Comment: Try if JAXB can handle the XML.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I'm also thinking now about changing XML after getting response from API but before parsing this response. But it seems like very dirty solution.